# How to use interval in alpine js?

Tags: alpine.js

I am trying to add a timer to my cards. So, what I do is. I receive data from DB and pass the data to the `records[]` array and then I show the data on frontend.

```
<template x-for="record in records">
    <span x-text="record.created_at">2022-10-31 18:41:20</span>
</template>
```

But what I want is to show the seconds between `created at` to `now time` and the seconds should be changed as time passes kind of like how much time is passed since the record is created.

Actually, in my case, I need to change the text within the loop. I tried something like this

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kevinbatdorf/alpine-magic-helpers@latest/dist/interval.js

<template x-for="record in records">
    <span x-text="$interval(getTimer(record), 1000)">2022-10-31 18:41:20</span>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function dateComponent() {
        return {
            init: function() {
                // fetch data
            },
            getTimer: function(record) {
                console.log(record)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But this runs the interval only once. Is this possible in alpine js. and if yes, please guide me to where I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you setup a codepen or such, it would make it easier to help